# How to copy a range of cells to another column in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Working Environment: Excel 2013

Target: Copy C1:C9 to B11:B19. D1:D9 to B21:B29. E1:E9 to B31:B39.....

After copying all the range to column B, copy A1:A9 to A11:A19(A21:A29....)

My idea is that:
1. select a range by using something like

```
     range.end()
```

because in some of my sheets, there are only 4 test steps. so I need a syntax which can self inspect the used cells in a column.

2. do a range copy to column B.
3. leave 1 row in between considering about the page layout.

My piece of code is:

```
Worksheets("Master").Columns(3).UsedRange.Copy
Worksheets("Master").Range("B11").PasteSpecial
```

but seems like the Columns(i).UsedRange.Copy doesn't work. the pastespecial works.

My question is：

How to select the used range in columns? The number of columns are not fixed which means some of the sheets have 40 columns, but some of the other have maybe 30.

Thanks!

I attached one screenshot of the sheet for your reference.[image: Screenshot of the sheet]

Comment: The used range always includes the area from top left to right bottom. It is possible that there will be blank cells at top and bottom, and that `UsedRange.Columns(1)` isn't column A. The easiest way for you to deal with the possible presence of blank cells is to include them in the pasted range.

Comment: So you want to copy Columns C onwards to column B . If your columns to be copied don't have any other data you can use `Range("C1:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` to get all data in column C

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not have more data in the columns to be copied, this should work

```
Sub copyToOneColumn()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")

    Dim startCol As Integer
    startCol = 3

    Dim endCol As Integer
    endCol = 10

    Dim startRange As Range
    Dim ra As Range


    For i = startCol To endCol
        Set startRange = ws.Range("A1").Offset(0, i - 1)
        Set ra = ws.Range(startRange, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, startRange.Column).End(xlUp))
        ra.Copy Destination:=ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a copy (not technically a copy as it doesn't use the clipboard) directly like so:

```
Range("B1").Resize(Range("A1:A" & range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count,1) = Range("A1:A" & range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

Effectively you are looking at B1 then resizing that to a range to be the number of columns in column A that are used with this: `Range("A1:A" & range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count`

Then you are making this new range in column B = to the values of the same range in column A.

Note, this can be shortened if you are always starting at row 1 but the code I have given you will suffice if you start at a different row.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, r As Long, c As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wsMaster = Sheets("Master")
lr = wsMaster.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lc = wsMaster.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
r = lr + 2
If lr <= 9 Then
    For c = 3 To lc
        wsMaster.Range(wsMaster.Cells(1, c), wsMaster.Cells(lr, c)).Copy wsMaster.Range("B" & r)
        wsMaster.Range("A1:A" & lr).Copy wsMaster.Range("A" & r)
        r = wsMaster.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 2
    Next c
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```